# Is this Thuja Green Giant overwatered or underwatered?

Tags: tree-care, evergreens

[image]

I planted 5 1ft Thuja Green Giants from fastgrowingtrees.com in the winter and they all died from overwatering. At first I followed the watering guide that the website recommends but then noticed one was dying so I got worried and ended up flooding all of them.

I'm now on my second batch of green giants (planted in the spring) and the summer has reached triple digit temperatures. (I'm in southern Idaho). I've been watering all my green giants via sprinkler every other day, expect for the tree shown in the photo because the sprinklers don't reach it. To compensate, I've been lightly watering it every other day with the hose. This is the spot where the first one died last time, and it's the first to start dying this time. The needles just turned brittle. I watered yesterday and tested the soil moisture this morning and found it's on the low end of moist. I'm hesitant to water it more for fear of overwatering (the website recommends twice a week in hot temperatures at this stage, and I've already doubled that).

Can anyone tell by the photo whether it needs more or less water? It's planted in MiracleGro Tree & Shrub soil with mulch on top.

Thanks!

Comment: What is underneath the "tree and shrub soil?" If trees can't grow deep roots to find water, they won't thrive. Frequent light watering can be a bad thing, because it encourages shallow surface roots which make the plant highly dependent on your artificial watering.